# Storing std::to_string(x).c_str() in member variable produces garbage

Tags: c++, xcode

I have this very simple C++ program:

```
using namespace std;

class TheClass
{
private:
    const char *_numberString;

public:
    TheClass(int number)
    {
        _numberString = to_string(number).c_str();
    }

    operator const char *()
    {
        return _numberString;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   TheClass instance = 123;
   cout << (const char *)instance << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

When I run it in Xcode, it logs `\367\277_\377`. If I change it to this however:

```
using namespace std;

class TheClass
{
public:   // Change 1/2
    const char *_numberString;

public:
    TheClass(int number)
    {
        _numberString = to_string(number).c_str();
    }

    operator const char *()
    {
        return _numberString;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    TheClass instance = 123;
    instance._numberString = to_string(123).c_str();   // Change 2/2
    cout << (const char *)instance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

it logs `123` like it should. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Even if I change 123 to another number the exact same thing is logged.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to resort to `char*`. The `operator <<` for iostream handles `std::string` just fine.

Comment: @Cyber I don't see that Q&A is really a dupe. I was actually willing to close this question for it, but the linked question missed at least to provide a MCVE, while this one does. Also the situation described is slightly different, and it's even not obvious from the given answers what's actually going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point

```
 _numberString = to_string(number).c_str();
```

you are storing a pointer to the interned data of a temporary `std::string` value, that is invalidated after that line of code.

Accessing `_numberString` effectively calls undefined behavior.

---

As mentioned in comments, there's no point to keep the `_numberString`<sup>1</sup> member as `const char*`. Use a `std::string` member instead:

```
class TheClass {
private:
     std::string  numberString_;

public:
    TheClass(int number) : numberString_(to_string(number)) {
    }

    operator const std::string& () {
         return numberString_;
    }
};
```

---

<sub>1) You shouldn't use prefixed `_` for class member names, that's reserved for compiler and standard implementation intrinsics. If you dislike patterns like `m_` or other prefix conventions (like me), just use a postfix `_` as shown in my sample.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The return value of c_str is only valid for as long as the string is in scope (and unaltered). Your anonymous temporary goes out of scope at the end of the statement.

Consider having a std::string as a member variable rather than a pointer type, or store the numeric value itself.

Answer (score 1):

`c_str()` returns a pointer to the buffer of the `std::string` instance it's call on. The object returned by `std::to_string()` is a temporary and is destroyed at the end of the constructor body. That leaves `_numberString` pointing to an object that has since been destroyed.

The second piece of code doesn't have to work. You have the same problem as in the first one. The fact that it works is an effect of undefined behavior.